# angularjs: sharing data between controllers (loading HTML )

Tags: angularjs

i know this question has been asked many times but i have a different issue related to sharing data between controllers.

**index.html**

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController"><div>LeftPanel</div>  <div ng-include src="RitePanel"></div></div>
```

in Leftpanel all documents get loaded and when any document gets clicked i change value of RitePanel that brings new html in "RiteDiv"

```
 switch (document.status) {            
        case 1://Draft
            $scope.RitePanel= '/Scripts/app/home/templates/primary-right-panel/draft-panel.html';
            break;
        case 2://Completed
            $scope.RitePanel= '/Scripts/app/home/templates/primary-right-panel/completed-panel.html';
            break;
```

sharingservice.setobject(document.id);

i have created controller for each Html e.g draftcontroller for Draft-html and completedcontroller for completed-html these are child controllers

i created a sharing service to share data between Top and child controllers

```
 adocsModule.factory('SharingService',  function ($rootScope) {

var service = {
    setobject: function (object) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('docobject', object);
    }
};
return service;});
```

and in child controllers i do

```
   adocsModule.controller('draftcontroller ', ['$scope', 'SharingService', function ($scope, sharingservice) {   
$scope.$on('docobject', function (event, clientDataObject) {        
    alert(clientDataObject); //i know its not recommended its just for testing purpose
    console.log('pendingcontroller ' + clientDataObject);
    $scope.test = clientDataObject;
});}]);
```

HTML:

```
   <div ng-controller="draftcontroller "> <span>{{test}}</span></div>
```

**Issue:**

on first click on document(LeftPanel) nothing gets prompted and when i click it again i see alert and also changes in html (RitePanel)
what i feel is its because of on first click HTML isn't loaded yet may  be because of that  child controller doesn't listen ?

child controllers loaded at page load they are not loaded dynamically. just HTML that gets loaded dynamically

any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

could you complete/edit my plunker. I don't uderstand where the setobject() method of the SharingService service is trigered.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zX7o3L?p=preview)

Comment: sory My mistake, it happens in main controller. i have edited it in my question

Comment: i have solved it using $timeout i think it was happening as Broadcast happen before HTML loaded